# Astra Linux 1.7 Foreman-Installer

Tags: astra-linux

При попытке установки foreman-installer выдает ошибку

```
Enable to locate package apache2-mpm-worker
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/2.5.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
```

Answer (score 1):

Для справки скажу:

1.перед этим был установлен puppetserver.

2. все пакеты устанавливались из официального репозитория.

И так для корректной установки мне понадобилось.

```
apt install libpq5=11.17-astra.se3
apt-mark hold libpq5
apt install libpq-dev=11.17-astra.se3
apt-mark hold libpq5
apt install postgresql-client-11=11.17-astra.se3
apt-mark hold postgresql-client-11
```

всё приходится холдить так как при установке foreman-installer иначе всё слетает

далее настраиваем локали (после этого ваш сервер перейдет на английский язык)

```
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
```

в моем случаи в таблице была под 158-мым номером и 3 сделать по умолчанию

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

перезагружаемся

```
apt install foreman-installer
foreman-installer
```

после этого должен появится вход по http://hostname.domain.ru

через консоль сразу можно создать пользователя

```
foreman-rake permissions:reset username=sergey password=1234
```